# Use of logical || with constant operand

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a few defines like this:

```
#define flag   YES
#define prod   YES
#define test   NO
```

these are used for tests.

At one point of code I have

```
BOOL testMode = flag || prod || test;
```

Xcode whines with this message: **use of logical || with constant operand... fix it using bitwise**

but the operation I am doing is logical, not bitwise.

I want testMode to be YES if one of the 3 states are YES.

Any clues?

Comment: It thinks you're doing something wrong and it wants to "help" you.

Comment: It a surprising warning.  I cannot reproduce by pasting your code into a source file.

Comment: @danh yeah I used the same code and get no warning..

Comment: I was able to reproduce it... Seems like you can replace the code with `BOOL testMode = flag | prod | test;` and get the same result without the warning. It may be a matter of what would bother you more... an unnecessary warning or using the bitwise `|` operator for what's essentially a logical operation.

Comment: Ok, in this case I see that a bit wise is the same as OR, but this error is stupid, because this can create confusion.

Comment: It seems designed to catch people incorrectly using the logical operators with bit fields. You wouldn't want to accidentally write `bitField || 0x4` when you're trying to set bit 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code gets the same result without the warning.

```
BOOL testMode = flag | prod | test;
```

It may be a matter of what would bother you more... an unnecessary warning or using the bitwise `|` operator for what's essentially a logical operation. The warning seems designed to catch people incorrectly using the logical operators with bit fields. You wouldn't want to accidentally write `bitField || 0x4` when you're trying to set bit 2.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler really can't tell the difference between YES, NO, and 0x7341 -- they're just numerical values.  So it guesses that you're trying to do some sort of bit setting/masking operation and have erroneously used "logical" operators.

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer this one:

```
BOOL testMode = (BOOL)flag || (BOOL)prod || (BOOL)test;
```

Comment: Best solution, as it applies for any situation. However, isn't `bool` and not `BOOL`?

Answer (score 1):

The warning goes away with:

```
#define flag   true
#define prod   true
#define test   false
```